# Comparing rows in MS access tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates, subquery, ms-access-2007

I have such values in these two table. I want to check duplicates  in TableA and TableB

```
    TABLEA
    StaffName   Shift   Hrs
    ABC           1      12
    DEF                  23
    XYZ           2          


    TABLEB
    StaffN       Sft   Hrs
    ABC           1      12
    DEF                  23
    XYZ           2
```

However when i do a

```
  SELECT * FROM TABLEA 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT * FROM TABLEB.StaffN = TABLEA.StaffName AND
  TABLEB.Sft = TABLEA.Shift AND
  TABLEB.Hrs = TABLEA.Hrs);
```

Why would i be returned of DEF and XYZ? is it becuz of the empty value? And how can i change my select statment to check if both value empty, its the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you were right to suspect Nulls.

Consider the 3 values in the "DEF" rows: DEF; Null; and 23.  A human might say those rows are duplicates because all 3 values are the same in both tables.

However, the subquery asks the db engine to consider whether `TABLEB.Sft = TABLEA.Shift`.  And there is the problem ... a Null can never be equal to anything, not even another Null.

See whether this Immediate window session clarifies the situation.

```vba
? 1 = 1
True
? 1 = 2
False
? 1 = Null
Null
? Null = Null
Null
```

So when both fields are Null, the comparison `TABLEB.Sft = TABLEA.Shift` is evaluated as Null.  The db engine will only include rows where the comparison is `True`, so those "DEF" rows are excluded.  And the same logic explains why the "XYZ" rows are excluded.

You need a comparison which returns `True` when both `TABLEB.Sft` and `TABLEA.Shift` are Null, and also returns `True` when both contain the same non-Null values.

```
(TABLEB.Sft Is Null AND TABLEA.Shift Is Null)
OR
(TABLEB.Sft = TABLEA.Shift)
```

Try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    TABLEA AS a
    INNER JOIN TABLEB AS b
    ON a.StaffName = b.StaffN
WHERE
    (
        (a.Shift Is Null AND b.Sft Is Null)
        OR
        (a.Shift = b.Sft)
    )
    AND
    (
        (a.Hrs Is Null AND b.Hrs Is Null)
        OR
        (a.Hrs = b.Hrs)
    );
```

Comment: wa but i got 27 columns, meaning have to do it the hard way?

Comment: Yeah, that's a challenge.  But it would have been a challenge to expand your original approach to 27 columns, too.  You can use `Nz()` as @sgeddes suggested provided none of the stored numbers are zeros.  Or substitute some other "magic" number instead of zero ... if all the stored numbers are positive, you could use `Nz(a.Shift, -1) = Nz(b.Sft, -1)` in the comparison.

Comment: Beware `Nz()` can only be used when the query is run from within an Access session.  If you need to run the query from outside Access (like from Dot.Net or Classic ASP), `Nz()` will not be available.  In that case you can use `IIf()` instead: `IIf(a.Shift Is Null, -1, a.Shift) = IIf(b.Sft Is Null, -1, b.Sft)`  Nulls are challenging!

Comment: May i ask, in access, empty values means null? sry not used to access

Comment: If you have a text or memo field which contains an empty string (a string value of 0 length, ""), that field would appear "empty".  But that kind of empty is not the same as Null. For dates, Yes/No, and other number fields, empty means Null.

Comment: Ya thats where i am confuse. My columns are Text. How do i identify if that row that appears empty, is it a empty string or null?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23753/discussion-between-hansup-and-10e5x)

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your where criteria around the `NZ` function to see if that helps, like:

```
NZ(TABLEB.Hrs,0) = NZ(TABLEA.Hrs,0)
```